# Qt Composition mode. Black or white depending on background

Tags: qt, background, composition, foreground, qpainter

I would like to draw a cross over an image, with a different color for each pixel depending on the background color, so that the cross is always well visible. So I'm trying to change the Composition Mode of the `QPainter`, but I can't find an acceptable solution.

I have tried `QPainter::CompositionMode_Difference`, painting with white. This is quite good because it inverts the destination color, but it doesn't work well if the destination color is a middle gray or similar.

The best solution is to get white if the background is "dark" and black if the background is "light". Is there a way to get this effect using only composition modes of the painter?

Answer (score 0):

What about running the [Image Composition Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-painting-imagecomposition-example.html) for yourself, and maybe modifying the source/destination images to better fit your scenario? Maybe QPainter::CompositionMode_Xor is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution, which is even very simple, is to use a white cross with a rather thick black outline. In this case you can ensure the visibility of the cross even in case of rather dark or light background images.